# C++ LoadImage Bug Exclusive to Release Mode

Tags: c++, image, winapi, bitmap

I've been trying to do something supposedly simple, but as usual, it's not working for me, in dubious circumstances. What I want to do is simply load a bitmap to the screen and keep it there. The (popup) window will have no controls, cannot be moved, and will only handle WM_PAINT through it's pump; like a splash screen.

The code compiles fine and runs fine during debug mode, but when I switch to release mode  `LoadImage()` invariably returns `NULL` and everything else fails as a result. This is my fourth hour spent on this one method and I think it's time to ask for help.
I have checked for uninitialized memory and can ensure that every class member used is initialized to `0`, and am reasonably sure that this is not the problem.
I'll post the code below, and thanks a lot for your help.

I'd prefer to only do this using WinAPI, if possible, because I won't have a use for this functionality anywhere else in this application. Of course I'm still open to ideas, but most likely I'm just making a stupid error. Again, thanks!

---

```
int CreateWindowWithUserFormat()
{   
    SIZE BMSize = {0};
    LoadedBitmap = (HBITMAP) LoadImage(NULL,
    L"Art\\Splash_Screens\\1.bmp", IMAGE_BITMAP,
    NULL, NULL, LR_LOADFROMFILE);

    if(!LoadedBitmap) {
    MessageBox(NULL,
        L"Error loading image to void * HBITMAP",
        L"Error Loading Splash", NULL);
    }

    ScreenDevCtxt = CreateCompatibleDC(NULL);
    if(!ScreenDevCtxt) {
    //Failure
    }

    ReplacedObject = SelectObject(ScreenDevCtxt, (HGDIOBJ) LoadedBitmap);
    if(ReplacedObject == NULL || ReplacedObject == HGDI_ERROR) {
    //Failure
    }

    if( (!GetBitmapDimensionEx(LoadedBitmap, &BMSize) ) ||
    BMSize.cx == 0 || BMSize.cy == 0) {
    //Failure, try alternate:
        BITMAP Bm = {0};
    if( (!GetObject(LoadedBitmap, sizeof(Bm), &Bm) ) ||
        Bm.bmWidth == 0 || Bm.bmHeight == 0) {

    MessageBox(NULL,
        L"Error getting bitmap size; loading aborted.",
        L"Error Loading Splash Image", NULL); 
    }
    // Alternate success; use these as size.
    BMSize.cx = Bm.bmWidth;
    BMSize.cy = Bm.bmHeight;
    }

    {
    RECT WindowSize = {0};
    WinHelper.CenterRectInScreen(WindowSize, BMSize.cx, BMSize.cy);

    if(!Create(L"TitleName",
        WS_POPUPWINDOW | WS_EX_TOPMOST,
        WS_EX_TRANSPARENT,
        WindowSize.left, WindowSize.top,
        WindowSize.right, WindowSize.bottom,
        NULL, NULL) )
    {
        return false;
    }
    return true;
    }
}
```

---

It's probably worth mentioning that this runs on it's own thread. The thread wrapper is responsible for destroying this window when it receives a signal from the application and a certain time has passed (5 seconds, I believe). I'm reasonably sure this isn't the root of the problem, but who knows; I'm out of ideas. 
The problem only arises in release mode, and yes, the release mode still has access to the file (`Art\\Splash_Screens\\1.bmp`). What can I do to solve this?

**Update**
Well, it only took a few minutes after this to realize the path was the error...
I still don't know *why*, but apparently it works fine if we take out the intermediate folders and stick `"1.bmp"` directly next to the executable. Thank you guys.

Comment: Your image load path looks relative to your cwd. You do have deployed below your executable the images? Or does the debug build deploy to the "right" location and the release build to a not so right one?

Comment: @JonathonReinhart In order to verify I simply copied the entire "Art" folder directly into the location of the release executable.

Comment: @JonathonReinhart Okay, well you were right -- Doesn't make too much sense to me, but moving `1.bmp` out of the intermediate directory and putting it directly next to the .exe lets it work fine. Can I accept a comment as an answer?

Comment: @user2085046 Moved everything to an answer.

Comment: @user2085046 Also note, that this isn't a forum - we don't mark questions as "SOLVED" by editing the title. The presence of an accepted answer is what indicates the problem has been solved.

Comment: @JonathonReinhart Okay, thanks. I accepted your answer and I'll keep that in mind. I'll edit the title back.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Often times, I notice that issues like this are path-related.  Note that it doesn't matter where the release executable lives, but rather what the "current [working directory](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Working_directory)" is.

You can get the currect working directory with the [`getcwd`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009695399/functions/getcwd.html) or (in Win32) [`GetCurrentDirectory`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa364934.aspx) function calls.

As an additional test, to make sure that the file is indeed where you belive it is (relative to your CWD), I would throw in an `fopen(..., "r")` call, and check that it succeeds.

Answer (score 0):

When you execute your app from your IDE the working directory is your project directory. But when you release as a debug/release your IDE will put your app into a folder projectfolder/bin/debug(release). Now its working directory is not your projectfolder but projectfolder/bin/debug(release). This is the reason why it finds your bitmaps while running in the IDE but not after release as debug/release.

You can do as follows:

The path to your bitmap is for example "yourProjectFolder/image/bitmap1.bmp". You can run inside your IDE -> no problem.
Your code looks like this:

```
LoadedBitmap = (HBITMAP)LoadImage(NULL,
               "image/bitmap1.bmp", IMAGE_BITMAP,
               NULL, NULL, LR_LOADFROMFILE);
```

Now you want to release as a debug. The working directory is now projectfolder/bin/debug so change the search path to:

```
LoadedBitmap = (HBITMAP)LoadImage(NULL,
               "../../image/bitmap1.bmp", IMAGE_BITMAP,
               NULL, NULL, LR_LOADFROMFILE);
```

For each ../ the IDE will step one folder level up. Which means from here: projectFolder/bin/debug to here: projectfolder/image the machine has to step two times up till it reaches the projectfolder plus /image for you image folder. So ../../image leads to projectfolder/image from bin/debug.

But this is a work around! Its better to load the image from a resource.

Comment: Three years later!?  If I hadn't figured out the typo in my path-name by now, I doubt that I would still be working on it!  :)